# Issues with Very Simple JSON-P Example

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-mobile, cross-domain, jsonp

I am trying to build a mobile app that will grab json data that will be output from a php query of a mysql database. This is the first time I have done this, so was just trying a simple example to get things to work. All seems fine when on the same domain, but I am having issues getting json-p to work for a cross domain fetch. The same domain code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>the title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('example.json', function(staff) {
         document.write(staff.name);
      });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

That works great, but when I move the example.json to another domain and test, it is no longer functioning. I added ?callback=? to the end of the url as I have read about on various tutorials, but it is not loading anything. Changed the one line to:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.knoxyouthgroup.org/example.json?callback=?', function(staff) {
```

Not sure where to go from here, kind of hit a wall. Sorry for the newbie question, but any help would be really appreciated!

Our end goal is to build a mobile app from json data we host. Data would be pretty simple and minimal, is that something you can host on your own? I keep reading about REST services and such, but am not sure if this is just something I could write a php script for and dump it to json and call it a day?

Thanks all!

Comment: Have you tried using firebug and checking the request and response headers?

Comment: did the example still work, if you tried to execute it with the local json-file after modifying the `getJSON()`-line?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I added ?callback=? to the local example and it stopped working too. Does this mean the callback is not done correctly?

Comment: Good idea @papirtiger. When I do this, the status on the GET says 301 Moved Permanently. Do you know what that means, or how to resolve?

Comment: This is really tough... any help would be great! The script works just fine with a local call, and even works when doing a call to say Twitter, but any call to json of my own, cross domain does not work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

JSONP works differently than plain JSON, both client and service must adhere to the rules for it to work:

1. Client
   Using JQuery.getJSON, specify "callback=?" to inform JQuery that you are doing a JSONP call. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
2. Service
   Service must handle a JSONP call correctly by wrapping the response JSON with the callback function. It should return a response in the format:

   ```
     <callback-function> ( <JSON-payload> )
   ```

e.g.,     callback({name:"JONES",position: "Officer"})

If the service is just returning , the client fails silently.

I suspect your service is not JSONP-compliant, rewrite it to handle both local(JSON) and remote (JSONP) calls.